# How to Sort main entry screen in Date descending order

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Good morning to all,

I am developing in acumatica mobile, so far everything is correct, but it is required that the entry date of the screen be ordered in descending order by date.

I have modified the graph view to achieve this but it appears to be the same.

I am attaching my code so that you can guide me and know where I am wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
add screen XP302000 {
  
add container "Document" {
  
 add recordAction "Save" {
 behavior = Save
 }
  
 add recordAction "Cancel" {
 behavior = Cancel
 }
  
 add containerAction "Insert" {
 behavior = Create
 }
  
 add recordAction "Delete" {
 behavior = Delete
 }
  
 add recordAction "ReleaseAction" {
 syncLongOperation = true
 behavior = Record
 }
  
 add recordAction "CreateSalesOrdersAction" {
 behavior = Record
 }
  
 add recordAction "SignReport" {
 behavior = SignReport
 displayName = "Sign"
 }
 
 attachments {
 imageAdjustmentPreset = Receipt
 }
  
 fieldsToShow = 5
 formActionsToExpand = 5
 add  layout "RenderedHeader" {
     layout = "HeaderSimple"
 add layout "RenderedHeaderRow1" {
     layout = "Inline"
 add field "ServiceTicketNbr"
 #add field "OrderTotal"
 }
 add layout "RenderedHeaderRow2" {
     layout = "Inline"
 add field "Status"
 #add field "OrderNbr"
 }
 add layout "RenderedHeaderRow3" {
     layout = "Inline"
 add field "Date"
 }
}
  
add field "Project" {
      selectorDisplayFormat = KeyDescription
      pickerType = Searchable
}    
add field "CustomerID"
add field "LocationID"
add field "CountyID"  
add field "Branch"
add field "JobType"  
add field "Sub"  
  
add layout "CheckTypeRow" {
      displayName = "CheckTypeRow"
      layout = "Inline"
      add field "Hold"
      add field "Billable"
  }    
add field "PONumber"
add field "NoteText" {
      displayName = "Notes"
      textType = PlainMultiLine
}  
add field "Summary"
  

add layout "FieldEntry" {
  layout = DataTab
  add containerLink "FieldEntry" {
  control = "ListItem"
  }
}
  
add layout "ScaleTickets" {
 layout = DataTab
 add containerLink "ScaleTickets" {
 control = "ListItem"
 }
}
  
add layout "EquipUsed" {
 layout = DataTab
 add containerLink "EquipUsed" {
 control = "ListItem"
 }
}

add layout "ProdQtyCompleted" {
 layout = DataTab
 add containerLink "ProdQtyCompleted" {
 control = "ListItem"
 }
}

add layout "OtherApplicationInfo" {
 layout = DataTab
 add containerLink "OtherApplicationInfo" {
 control = "ListItem"
 }
}  

  
}
  
add container "FieldEntry" {
 containerActionsToExpand = 1
add field "ProductSold"
add field "RoadName"
add field "UOM"
add field "QtyApplied"
add field "NoteText"
  
 add recordAction "Save" {
 behavior = Save
 }
 add recordAction "Cancel" {
 behavior = Cancel
 }
 add containerAction "Insert" {
 behavior = Create
 }
 add recordAction "Delete" {
 behavior = Delete
 }
 add recordAction "ReleaseAction" {
 syncLongOperation = true
 behavior = Record
 }  
}
  
add container "ScaleTickets" {
add field "TicketNbr"
add field "InventoryID"
add field "UOM"
add field "QtyUsed"
add field "NoteText"
  
 add recordAction "Save" {
 behavior = Save
 }
 add recordAction "Cancel" {
 behavior = Cancel
 }
 add containerAction "Insert" {
 behavior = Create
 }
 add recordAction "Delete" {
 behavior = Delete
 }
 add recordAction "ReleaseAction" {
 syncLongOperation = true
 behavior = Record
 }
}
  
add container "EquipUsed" {
add field "EquipmentID"
add field "EquipType"
add field "Hours"
add field "NoteText"
  
 add recordAction "Save" {
 behavior = Save
 }
 add recordAction "Cancel" {
 behavior = Cancel
 }
 add containerAction "Insert" {
 behavior = Create
 }
 add recordAction "Delete" {
 behavior = Delete
 }
 add recordAction "ReleaseAction" {
 syncLongOperation = true
 behavior = Record
 }
}
  
add container "ProdQtyCompleted" {
add field "EmulsionGallons"
add field "AggregateTons"
add field "TonsofOil"
add field "SquareYards"
add field "LineStripingLF"
add field "WaterGallons"
add field "MoistureContent"
add field "Cement"
add field "Fiber"
add field "FogSeal"
add field "AddFlaggers"
add field "Other"
}

add container "OtherApplicationInfo" {
add field "ApplicationRate"
add field "AsphaltTemp"
add field "AggregateSize"
add field "AirTemperature"
add field "TimeofDay"
add field "StoneCondition"
add field "RoadCondition"
add field "StoneSampleTaken"
add field "OilSampleTaken"
add field "StoneBoxesUsed"
add field "RoadSwept"
add field "TrafficControlEnforced"
add field "RoadSprayPatched"
add field "RoadTrueAndLeveled"
add field "Weather"  
}

  
}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't those views just based on GIs ?

Comment: I think so.  The mobile app is just a wrapper for the UI.  To sort the records, it must be done at the data view or delegate level